# angularJS route Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So yeah here is my HTML and scripts witch get an error.. and i don't know why i just follow a tutorial on pluralsight shouldn't have much problems, but no..

```
    <body>

    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#/NewEvent">Create Event</a></li>
                <li><a href="/templates/EditProfile.html">Edit Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="/templates/Event.html">Refresh</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div ng-view></div>



    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>  

    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="Content/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Content/underscore-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="Content/EditEventController.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/EventController.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

and here is my app.js:

```
 var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/NewEvent',
        {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tmp/Event.html',
            controller: 'EventController'


        })


});
```

and here is the error:

```
var ngRouteModule = angular.module('ngRoute', ['ng']).
                                provider('$route', $RouteProvider);
```

with the error Message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined"

Please help..

Comment: Are you sure that the angular is indeed loaded?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

First, you declare the name of your own module, then you declare a list of modules your very own module depends on.

```
var ngRouteModule = angular.module('yourModule', ['listOfModules']).
```

In this case listOfModules contains `ngRoute`